# Is it possible to spin a pickerview control automatically by detecting the iphone shake gesture?

Tags: uipickerview, gesture, shake

I am new to the apple technology and i am developing an application for iphone(iOS), i am facing a problem while developing an application (i,e) the pickerview should automatically scrolls or selects values by detecting the iphone shake gesture, whether is it possible. I know that ***-(void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event***  method detects the iphone shake gesture but doubt is how can i code inside this method for pickerview control to select values with respect to the gesture.

I am trying for the solution for the last two weeks but i didn't get it, if i will get the solution for this then it will be very happy for me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
sakthi